# Confuse about the AngularJS scope when multiple directives share same element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

All:

I'm new to AngularJS directive scope and I want to know how AngularJS deals with scope when multiple isolated-scope directives are assigned to teh same element.

For example:

```
app.controller("main", function($scope){
    $scope.data = [
        {
            id:"id_1"
        },
        {
            id:"id_2"
        },
        {
            id:"id_3"
        },
        {
            id:"id_4"
        }
    ];
});

app.directive("isodir", function(){
    return {
        restrict:"AE",
        scope: {},
        controller: function($scope){$scope.d = {id:"isodir_id"} },
        link: function(scope, EL, attrs){}
    }
});
```

The HTML part is:

```
<isodir ng-repeat="d in data track by $index">{{d.id}}</isodir>

<isodir>{{d.id}}</isodir>
```

There are mainly two questions that confused me so much:

> [1] For the html part[1]: the one with ng-repeat, could anyone give me
> some explanation on **how** AngularJS decides whose scope to use, because
> ng-repeat and isodir are both isolated scope(according to the result,
> but it turns out that ng-repeat scope get applied and I want to know why
> not isodir is applied); sometimes if I use two directives both with isolated
> scopes, AngularJS will report error. **But** the ng-repeat does not report
> error.
>
> [2] For the html part[2]: the one without ng-repeat, let us say that I
> just accept the fact about part[1] without any doubt, then it means that
> the d inside ng-repeat scope **gets rendered** to {{d.id}}, but in part[2],
> I define $scope.d inside isodir controller, but **why** this d can **not** be
> useed as value of {{d.id}}

Thanks

Comment: 1) `ng-repeat` most definitely does not use an isolate scope. 2) Isolate scopes inherit nothing from any parent scopes and may not be shared

Comment: @Phil could you give a more detail explanation how the whole procedure running when angularJS fired up in my example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) It will be something to do with $compile order which where directive with higher priority will be executed first. ngRepeat has priority of 1000 which is higher than custom directive which is 0. 
But for your case it is due to ng-bind-html {{d.id}} that you use will not work  for custom directive because you have an isolate scope so it expects that {{d.id}} will be bound inside the directive template and not outside of it. I.e using template or templateUrl.

Check 1st plunkr which is fixed version of your directive

```
app.directive('isodir', function(){
return {
    restrict:"AE",
    priority: 0,
    template: "{{d.id}}",
    scope: {},
    controller: function($scope){$scope.d = {id:"isodir_id"} }
}
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/3noKzbJGMav7MBozW4i0?p=preview

As you can see the result is isodir as it is the latest being compile thus override ng-repeat d scope.

Compare it with 2nd plunkr which custom directives has higher priority than ngRepeat

```
app.directive('isodir', function(){
return {
    restrict:"AE",
    priority: 100000,
    template: "{{d.id}}",
    scope: {},
    controller: function($scope){$scope.d = {id:"isodir_id"} }
}
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/1RhF0LpvfBOaVPZju6Fr?p=preview

As you can see ng-repeat override {{d.id}} to use ngRepeat scope object.

2) As explained above, it is due to isolated scope. If you want to use {{d.id}} in your custom directive without template / template URL then you have to remove isolated scope.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, this helps a lot (though not fully understand, but got basic idea). There is one thing I want to verify: Phil gave me an answer that "ng-repeat most definitely does not use an isolate scope", I am not sure about this, I thought it creates isolate scope and use no matter ng-bin-html or transclude to get DOM inside it, am I wrong?

Comment: When I played with the first plunkr, one thing I found interesting is: if I remove the template attribute from custom dir, the {{d.id}} will be back to  id_1, id_2, id_3 ...my understanding about this is: if a directive has a template attribute, it will clear out everything inside and only put template there and bind variable from its scope(if it is isolate scope, in my case, the {{d.id}} in html is actually been removed forever and replace by the {{d.id}} in my template, they are not same. right? )

Comment: And if there is no template attribute, the directive will limit its scope without removing thing inside it, and when $compile meets the {{d.id}} in the html, it has no idea there is a scope from isodir, but only ng-repeat scope is the closest to access, so it renders value from ng-repeat? If this is generally correct, I wonder how does ng-repeat allow its scope affect the varible in html( I think it uses same structure format like isodir, but why it can affect variable inside it, is that because it can copy content inside it as its template?) ?

Comment: ng-repeat doesnt use isolated scope and it using transclude. Yes, template will replace your inner html content. ng-repeat able to translate the {d.id} in inner html as it is not using isolated scope. Isolated scope in directive is scope : {} and as you can see in https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js#L3 , ngRepeat doesnt use isolated scope.

Comment: Thanks, I will try more examples to understand this.